# How can I fix Retarget pose from mesh bug in unreal?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unreal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARpSs.gif)

I am using Unreal 5.1.1 version.

I am using ALS and converted it to a custom mesh through Retarget pose from mesh node.

How can I fix the bouncing phenomenon in the video?

I really don't know what part is the problem.